# Why does Dropbox want access to my Google Contacts when signing up?

Tags: privacy, dropbox, permissions

When I sign up for Dropbox using Google it is requesting Google Contacts permissions. (I did a few Google searches, but the information was about Android and iOS only).

[image: "Manage your contacts"]

Why does it want this, and what does it want to do with my contacts?

Is there any way to not allow it access to my contacts?

Why does it need to manage my contacts, not view?

Comment: I really wish that the Google interface had a 'disable' option for contacts where it would tell the service that, yeah, you have access to contacts, but the user seems to have zero contacts.

Answer (score 6):

There is an official version (for Android) [here](https://www.dropbox.com/help/mobile/android-access-contacts):

> **Why does the Dropbox Android app request access to my contacts?**
>
> The Android app uses your contacts to provide features that make it
>   easier for you to use Dropbox, including sharing with friends without
>   having to remember their contact info. For example, when you share
>   files and photos, Dropbox can suggest names and email addresses from
>   your address book as you type them.
>
> **Does Dropbox collect or save my contacts?**
>
> With your permission, Dropbox will sync information from your contacts
>   for your use.
>
> **Does Dropbox share my contacts with others?**
>
> We don’t share your contacts unless you request that we do so. If you
>   choose to share files with someone or invite a person to Dropbox, we
>   send an email on your behalf to that contact.
>
> **Can I use Dropbox without giving access to my contacts?**
>
> Starting with Android Marshmallow, users can grant optional
>   permissions when using an app instead of when installing an app. For
>   all users, Dropbox will only sync your contacts if you give us
>   permission to do so.
>
> **Why are contacts from a different device or app appearing in my Dropbox?**
>
> With your permission, Dropbox syncs contacts from devices on which you
>   use Dropbox. This feature makes it easy to share and collaborate with
>   all of your contacts directly from Dropbox, whether they're from a
>   linked device or a third-party source (Facebook, Google, Twitter, or
>   Yahoo).

To [Remove third-party service contacts](https://www.dropbox.com/help/account/remove-connected-services):

> Dropbox stores contacts from each third-party service you've connected
>   to your Dropbox account (such as Gmail or Yahoo). This feature makes
>   it easy to share and collaborate with all of your contacts directly
>   from Dropbox.
>
> Follow the steps below to remove third-party service contacts from
>   your Dropbox, but note that this action will disconnect all
>   third-party services.
>
> 1. Sign in at dropbox.com.
> 2. Click your name or avatar at the top of any page.
> 3. Click Settings.
> 4. Click Account, or click Personal if you have paired personal and work Dropbox accounts.
> 5. Under Connected services, click Remove all services and imported contacts.
> 6. Confirm this action in the pop-up window by clicking Remove all.

Comment: But what if I don't use the Android app and never plan to?

Answer (score 4):

This is not a definitive answer, but I feel the reason they would would give is:

When you are sharing a file, if they have your contacts, they can suggest you email address to share the link with.

That's what they do on mobile as well.

[image: screenshot]